# R shiny: How can I use textOutput for a title in a sidebarPanel?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a renderText expression, which produces a value (between 1 and 10) and I would like to use it for a title in a sidebar panel. I tried to use textOutput() as in the main panel. However, it didn't work. My goal would be to have something like the following:

```
h3(paste("the number should be", textOutput()))
```

Comment: If you'd `paste` inside the `renderText`, your expression will be fine. Or is there something else you want to achieve? If so, please be more precise on how you want the ui to look like.

Comment: @ argo. Thank you for the fast reply. This is one solution. However, suppose I have multiple questions I want to ask. And based on the answer, the value will change and I want to use that updated value in the next question. Your solution works perfect I guess. But what about if I want to change my question and not use the same phrasing all the time. This is why I thought it would be good to use the paste() expression in ui.R and not sever. R. Do you know what I mean? Thanks again!

Comment: Could you provide an example? From what you're saying, it might be even more useful to do everything inside a renderText expression.

Comment: I will - thank you. I'm on my phone right now but as soon as I'm on my computer, I will provide an example.